# How can I have a Listview display multiple columns?

Tags: c#, listview, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to make a ListView with images and its labels below each image. I use `LargeIcon` display mode since the `Tile` display display the labels and images side by side. My problem is that it does not display as many columns as many would fit, like in this screenshot it would fit two columns instead of one:

[[image: 1]]

Comment: Not clear with the way you want to achieve.  Also, Can you provide the code samples?

Comment: You are probably missing just one or too pixels..

Comment: Oh. It seems that ListView items need too much space on the right for some reason, [It works now](http://i.imgur.com/lCOOnXt.png), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help please add new control of listView with name lView1 in you form designer.

```
lView1.View = View.Details;
Add your columns
        lView1.Columns.Add("ID");
        lView1.Columns.Add("Name");

Add the listview items
        lView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]{"1", "name1"}));
        lView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]{"4", "name2"}));
        lView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]{"2", "name3"}));
```

Comment: Finally, something that actually works. Most the old accepted answers on stackoverflow do not work in 2019.